# Applying Torvalds' "Good Taste" to a Fortran linked list

Tags: c, recursion, linked-list, fortran, iteration

Several years ago, Linus Torvalds gave a ted talk where he showed a  linked list implementation that remove extraneous if tests by the use of pointers-to-pointers, which he deemed "Good taste".  A simple example is below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct list_entry {
    int val;
    struct list_entry *next;
};

void list_insert(struct list_entry **head, int val)
{
    while (*head)
        head = &(*head)->next;

    *head = calloc(1, sizeof(**head));
    (*head)->val = val;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct list_entry *head = NULL;

    list_insert(&head, 0);
    list_insert(&head, 1);

    printf("Entry 1: %d\n", head->val);
    printf("Entry 2: %d\n", head->next->val);      
}
```

I was able to make something similar to this work in fortran through the use of a recursive `list_insert` and fortran's call-by-reference semantics:

```
module list_type
    implicit none

    type :: list
        integer :: val
        type(list), pointer :: next => null()
    end type list

contains

    recursive subroutine list_insert(lst, val)
        type(list), pointer, intent(inout) :: lst
        integer :: val
        !-
        if (associated(lst)) then
            call list_insert(lst%next, val)
            return
        else
            allocate(lst)
            lst%val = val
        end if
    end subroutine list_insert

end module list_type

program list_test
    use list_type
    implicit none

    type(list), pointer :: head => null()

    call list_insert(head, 0)
    call list_insert(head, 1)
    call list_insert(head, 2)

    print *, head%val
    print *, head%next%val
    print *, head%next%next%val
end program list_test
```

Is there a way to make this work without resorting to recursion?  All my attempts have resulted in failure thus far.

EDIT:  Here's an example of my iterative approach not working

```
module list_type
    ...

    type :: list_ptr
        type(list), pointer :: p
    end type list_ptr

contains
    ...

    subroutine list_insert_iter(lst, val)
        type(list), pointer, intent(inout) :: lst
        integer :: val
        !-
        type(list_ptr)  :: walker

        walker%p => lst
        do while (associated(walker%p))
            walker%p => lst%next
        end do
        allocate(walker%p)
        walker%p%val = val
    end subroutine list_insert_iter

end module list_type

program list_test
    use list_type
    implicit none

    type(list), pointer :: head => null()

    call list_insert_iter(head, 0)   
    if (.not.associated(head)) stop "FAIL"

end program list_test
```

Comment: Where do you set next (shouldn't this be in the else part)? Why not the same construct as in C?

Comment: I was under the impression that `next` defaults to `null()` on the newly allocated entry due to the `next => null()` in the type definition.  Is that not the case?

Comment: It does. Why don't you just directly rewrite the C code using a pointer to pointer derived type?

Comment: @VladimirF I've added an example where I tried that

Comment: What does it mean "not working"?

Comment: @VladimirF the statement `stop "FAIL"` is executed.  Essentially the recurring problem I have is that if I use an iteration variable and allocate it, that allocation isn't connected to the passed in list.

Comment: Thanks @VladimirF. After seeing IanH's answer, I now see what you were saying about the pointer to pointer derived type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When dealing with pointers in Fortran, use of an intermediate wrapper type is often required.  The semantics of this wrapper type are closer to the semantics of a C pointer, than a bare Fortran POINTER.

As an example:

```
module list_type
    implicit none

    type :: list_ref
      type(list), pointer :: ref => null()
    end type list_ref

    type :: list
        integer :: val
        type(list_ref) :: next
    end type list
contains
    subroutine list_insert(lst_arg, val)
      type(list_ref), intent(inout), target :: lst_arg
      integer, intent(in) :: val

      type(list_ref), pointer :: lst

      lst => lst_arg

      do while (associated(lst%ref))
        lst => lst%ref%next
      end do

      allocate(lst%ref)
      lst%ref%val = val
    end subroutine list_insert
end module list_type

program list_test
    use list_type
    implicit none

    type(list_ref) :: head

    call list_insert(head, 0)
    call list_insert(head, 1)
    call list_insert(head, 2)

    print *, head%ref%val
    print *, head%ref%next%ref%val
    print *, head%ref%next%ref%next%ref%val
end program list_test
```

Comment: Thanks @IanH.  So my mistake was in trying to wrap the list up in a derived type rather than wrapping the pointer component of the list in a derived type.  Tricky.